# VBA Dec2Hex conversion doesn't work properly

Tags: vba, excel

I need to convert one particular column (E) from decimal to hexadecimal. The result should be placed in another column (in my case P).

The code I have works very well on every single cell in the E column, however when I have `516353` in the cell, for some reason the conversion goes wrong and instead of `7E101` written in column P, I get a `7E+101`...

I don't get why this happens only to this particular number even if my columns are set to Number type (I tried with General type too in Format Cells but it still doesn't change anything).

The code that i have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Range
Dim myRange As Range: Set myRange = Range("E2:E2000") 'define your range
Dim rcopy As Range
Dim myCopyRange As Range: Set myCopyRange = Range("P2:P2000") 'range for the converted values

For i = 1 To myRange.Cells.Count
    myCopyRange.Cells(i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(myRange.Cells(i).Value)
Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should add a `mycopyrange..NumberFormat = "@"` first

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! It solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're providing shorthand scientific notation into a cell with General formatting so Excel thinks you want conversion.  Set the range to Text format first; it won't harm the processing.

```
myCopyRange.numberformat = "@"

For i = 1 To myRange.Cells.Count
    myCopyRange.Cells(i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(myRange.Cells(i).Value)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about this, so the information was truly helpful.